# How to manipulate many elements inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that I want to show through a ng-repeat. But I have inside the div (with the ng-repeat) many other elements  which I want to manipulate for each iteration of that ng-repeat. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in result">
 {{data.name}} 
     <img src="value">
     <p class="class">text</p>
</div>
```

If I want to change the image source with a different source for each element of my array, how can I do this? I can't change anything of result array. I want to change it later, when the user clic in a bottom for example.

Daniel

EDIT:

img tag was just an example. I added other element which could be necessary to change the class. So a different class for each iteration.

Comment: Any you can make changes by using functions and like class="myfunction(somevalue)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the image source, use `ng-src` like:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in result">
 {{data.name}} <img ng-src="{{data.imageUrl}}">
</div>
```

In this I am assuming you have a property on each data item called `imageUrl`.

To change the value, just assign a new value to the `imageUrl` property and angular's two way bindings will do the rest. An example is:

```
<button ng-click="result[0].imageUrl = 'img/new-image.jpg';">Change Image</button>
```

Of course, you would want to make sure you have the correct index and that there is at least one element in the result array, but that should do it!

**Live Example**

To see this in action, check out the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gYLH7Z4b03lS2gZBHceC?p=preview

**EDIT**

Based on the edit to the question - if you need to change the class use `ng-class`. In fact, there is a directive already written for most of the common things that you need to change. Always search the angular documentation first: angularjs.org. If you do need to do something more advanced that isn't already written, read the documentation and create your own directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. Best of luck!

Comment: isn't there other way? Is inevitable to add "imageUrl"?

Comment: @Daniel976034 This is the best and easiest way. You can write a custom directive and there are probably lots more options, but this is the easiest. I'm writing a plunker quick which I will attach shortly. From there you can try it out and see what you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-src` instead of `src` for string interpolation. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will use ng-src